# socket.io What should I use rooms or namespaces?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a chat application, but I do not know if I should use rooms or namespaces and how to do it.

Roughly my application looks like this:

Sport (channel)

- Sport_A (sub-channel)
- Sport_B (sub-channel)

Politics (channel)

- Politics_A (sub-channel)
- Politics_B (sub-channel)
- Politics_C (sub-channel)

etc...

My requirements:

Non-auth users can only read messages in channels.
Auth users can both read and write messages in channels and sub-channels.

Non-auth users can be (join and leave) in multiple channels simultaneously.
Auth users can be (join and leave) in multiple channels and sub-channels simultaneously.
That means

It's a bit complicated, therefore I don't know where I should use rooms, where namespaces and how to handle authentication.

Now I have a default namespace '/', channels and sub-channels are rooms but where to perform authentication to not block non-auth users?

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token) {
    jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) return next(new Error('Socket authentication error'));
      socket.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next(new Error('Socket authentication error'));
  }
});
```

Comment: @jfriend00 I have found your answers very useful on other socket questions, can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `namespaces` are to be used when you need a separate endpoint or path. 
From the official documentation,

> This is a useful feature to minimize the number of resources (TCP
>   connections) and at the same time separate concerns within your
>   application by introducing separation between communication channels.

```js
// Server

const sportsIo = io.of('/s');

sportsIo.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected');
});
```

So essentially this means that for every namespace, your client (webapp) has to create a separate connection

```js
// Client

const sportsIo = io('/sports');

const politicsIo = io('/politics');
```

Now with every namespace, you can have one or more `rooms` (or `channels`) associated that sockets can join and leave.

```js
// Server

// at some point when you want to braodbast to the channel (room)
sportsIo.to('Sport_A').emit('some event');
```

```js
// Client

sportsIo.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('Sport_A');
  socket.join('Sport_B');
});
```

Refer https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ for more information.